# CORS - Firefox doesn't send API call even after successful OPTIONS response

Tags: cors

It's a authenticated API that I'm trying to call.. 
I can see that the OPTIONs call came back with 200 OK and proper response headers, still Firefox doesn't sends the API call,works perfectly on Chrome... Any ideas

Some values are hidden below..

> **Response Headers**
>   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: [POST, GET]
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
>   Date: Wed, 02 Oct 2013
>   20:52:02 GMT   Server: Mashery Proxy   Content-Length: 0
>
> **Request Headers**
>   OPTIONS /hello HTTP/1.1
>   Host: hidden
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
>   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Origin: hidden
>   Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
>   Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
>   Connection: keep-alive

Answer (score 0):

Why are the response methods inside of square brackets? They're supposed to be a comma separated list.

Comment: Will try to use some tool like fiddler and change the response and update if it worked.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with Firefox when letting Mashery handle the CORS request. My advice is turn off CORS support in Mashery and let your server handle it all.